# Set source block name for org section

Tags: org-mode, literate-programming

Expanding `<<foo>>` using noweb works with `#+NAME: foo` above one src block.

Why is this one not expanded?

```
 ** My org section
    :PROPERTIES:
    :header-args: NAME: foo
    :END:
     #+BEGIN_SRC sh
    pwd
     #+END_SRC
```

Comment: `#+NAME: foo` is not a header argument, so you cannot specify it as a property.

Comment: Thank you @NickD. Any other suggestions to set the name property once for all source blocks in the section?

Comment: Two points and a question: first, `#+NAME: foo` does *not* define a property (at least, not an *org* property: org properties belong to the containing heading, not to a source block); second, I don't know of any way to give a name once and have it become the name of all source blocks in the section. The question: why do you want to do that?  What are you trying to accomplish by giving to every source block the same name? E.g the results of *each* source block would go to the same `#+RESULTS: foo` section (overwriting the previous results, possibly from some other source block, ...

Comment: ..., also named `foo`). That would be very confusing IMO.